# Slow individual tree access for random forest in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to access the individual tree elements of a random forest model in PySpark. In particular, I am trying to get all the predictions from the individual trees; I need this for a particular reason.

Unfortunately the Spark ML API only exposes the individual trees but not the prediction.

- Pro: the individual trees can be used to make the predictions.
- Con: It looks to be really slow.

First, I fit a simple random forest model to an n=200 data set, with a 70/30 train/test split.

```python
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

# Create model
featureCols = ["age", "shoeSize", "score"]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols = featureCols,
                           outputCol = "features")

train_feat = assembler.transform(train)
test_feat = assembler.transform(test)

# Fit model
model = rf.fit(train_feat)
```

Then, I time:

- Predicting the random forest model on the test set
- Predicting a single tree on the test set

**Results for the random forest:**

```python
# How fast is the overall random forest prediction?
%timeit model.transform(test_feat).select('rowNum','probability')
%timeit model.transform(test_feat).select('rowNum','probability').collect()
```

```
24.9 ms ± 2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2.51 s ± 36.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Results for the individual tree:**

```python
# How fast is accessing a single tree?
%timeit model.trees[0].transform(test_feat).select('rowNum','probability')
%timeit model.trees[0].transform(test_feat).select('rowNum','probability').collect()
```

```
627 ms ± 12.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
3.12 s ± 280 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**KEY QUESTION: Why is it so much slower getting the results from an individual tree?**

I actually need all the predictions from all the trees (ie an ndata x nTree set), so looping over the individual trees is going to be really slow. With 500 trees I'm looking at ~ 0.6s x 500 trees = about five minutes minimum to get the predictions from all the trees).

Is there any fast way of getting all the individual tree predictions?  Do I need to go into Scala to do this?

**Alternative: Is there a vectorised way to do this?**

Even if the individual tree probability is somewhat slower, is there some way I can use the map/reduce functions to effectively vectorise this or farm out the individual computations without the overhead?

I attempted to do this by creating a vector

```python
treeNum = range(0,nTrees)
```

where nTrees=500, and then calculating a Cartesian join of this with my training data.

I tried to apply a UDF and index the model number I needed by treeNum but I couldn't work out how to do this within PySpark.